# ADF Pipeline Bulk copy activity to Log files

Tags: pipeline, bulk, azure-data-factory

I have a bulk copy template to azure blob storage data transfer set up in ADF. This activity will dynamically produce 'n' number of files. 
I need to write log file (txt format) after pipeline activity completed finished. 
The log file should have pipeline start & completion  datetime  and also number of files outputted, status etc.

What is the best way or to choose the activity to do this?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Thanks Jay. I am yet to try on this.I am trying to set up .net code in ADF. Will let you know once I have compelted.

Comment: Sure,Jyothi. Any updates,just post here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,i have to say that ADF won't generate log files about the execution information automatically. You could see [Visually monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually) and [Programmatically monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically) for activities in ADF.

In above link, you could get the `start time` of pipeline: `Run Start`.Even though it does not have any Run End, you could calculate by yourself: Run End = Run Start + Duration.

[image]

As for the number of files, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#monitor-programmatically).

[image]

Anyway,all these metrics need to be got programatically i think,you could choose the language you are good at.

Comment: Can i get the Activity Runs information into a database table, so that i can create a power bi report and share with monitoring team with my own charts and kpis